# genbarcode 0.4 - make: *** [.dep] Error 123

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, makefile, barcode

I am trying to install genbarcode 0.4 from http://www.ashberg.de/php-barcode/download/. On Centos 6.3 64bit.

Following the README I have installed barcode via yum (0.98-17.el6) then ran make in the genbarcode directory. I then get the following error:

```
creating depencies
rm -f .tmp.dep
gcc -M -Wall -I/usr/local/include ./genbarcode.c
./genbarcode.c:35:21: error: barcode.h: No such file or directory
make: *** [.dep] Error 123
```

I have also compiled and installed barcode 0.99 from source as per the README included in genbarcode, but get the same error. I have also tried moving the file mentioned 'barcode.h' into the directory with genbarcode but I then get errors about other missing files which I can't find.

I have already changed line 57 of the genbarcode Makfile to:

```
@find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.c" -print0 | xargs -n 1 -0t $(CC) -M $(CFLAGS)  >>.tmp.dep
```

Because it was producing a warning with the original:

```
@find . -name "*.c"   -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -n 1 -0t $(CC) -M $(CFLAGS)  >>.tmp.dep
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing `barcode-devel`, the `barcode` package doesn't include the files required for development/building against `barcode`, such as header files.